# Use android Application class run a thread background to post some data to webservice

Tags: multithreading, android

Could I write a thread in Android the Application class?
This thread is running every five minutes to post data to a webservice.

```
public class MyApplication  extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    startUploadGPSTimer();
}

private void startUploadGPSTimer() {
    gpsTimerHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 5* 60 * 1000); // start Timer
}

private Handler gpsTimerHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("latitude", Global.CUR_LATITUDE);
        params.put("longitude", Global.CUR_LONGITUDE);
        WebServiceObj obj = new WebServiceObj("upload",
                WebServiceMethod.METHOD_UPLOAD_GPS,
                Utilly.getSoapParams(params));
        SoapService service = null;
        SoapObject result = null;
        service = new SoapService(obj.tag);
        result = service.LoadResult(obj);
        Log.i("post webservrce  ", result.toString());
        gpsTimerHandler.postDelayed(this, 5 * 60 * 1000);
    }
};
```

When my application enter background, this thread like do not running. Because of the data I post in thread Finally input to Database, and I can't find it in db.

Why?

I write some log when do post data to webservice. and found the log be generated randomly.
   Very strange

Comment: Are you sure it is not running? Can't you just log something every N seconds and check if the problem is with Handler.

Comment: @ray its running, your problem may be with db entry.....

Comment: @AnandTiwari I'm sure the db is OK.  The db is on web, some other data could find in db...

Comment: @DmytroDanylyk  I write log. and I also can't find the log in logcat. In fact i found  randomly generate log , No rule.Very strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0,photosIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5*60*1000,5*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

In MyService is a Service Class write your stuff in onstart to send request to webservices. This service will call for every 5minutes.

Hope this helps.

Thanks